# How to convert ISO to IMA?

Tags: conversion, iso-image, disk-image

How to convert ISO to IMA ?

I know that converting to many other types (nrg,img,bin,cue,mdf,mds,ccd,sub) is easy.
I load them in UltraISO and save them as that formats. But it hasn't IMA type.
Also there are many tools, but not freeware.

Any ideas (on how to do it manually or with using tools)?

Comment: Can you specify why you want to do this, or what you're trying to achieve (unless this is just an academic exercise)?

Comment: @Karan, this is just an academic exercise ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia claims that IMA "is the same format as VFD", and VFD is a subset of VHD format apparently.

The VHD wiki article goes on to say that .VHD is a supported format by `vmware` and `virtualbox`, both of which are freeware/trialware as far as I know.

If it is not a bootable image, then you might simply mount the file as a disk within a VM and copy the contents manually, then create a new ISO image (etc).

( References: [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMA_%28file_format%29 ]; [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_%28file_format%29#Virtual_Floppy_Disk_.28VFD.29 ] )

Comment: `IMA` and `VFD` are just raw disk images, usually of floppy disks. (So it would be sufficient to rename `foo.iso` to `foo.ima`...) `VHD` is an entirely different format, mostly used by HyperV / VirtualPC for "dynamically expanding" disk images.

Comment: This is true in some case with disk image formats and not true in other cases (renaming). Do you have specific information regarding .IMA files which differs from what I provided in my answer (such as IMA being the same as VFD? Further, the VHD page has a section referencing VFD (which is in my link) which also states that it is supported by the freely available programs I suggested for mounting the image